# Viewport meta tag works on mobile safari, not on android

Tags: android, ios, mobile, safari, viewport

I'm using the following line in my webapp:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=720, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

This works perfectly fine on mobile safari - the document is 720px wide and fits the screen perfectly. However, when tested on the HTC One, the content was like 2.5x the width of the screen.

Android is supposed to support the viewport tag, so why is it ignoring the pixel width it should be displaying in?

All help appreciated.

Comment: What have you tested it on? iPhone, iPad? Which HTC One (there is a series of devices)?

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html):

> Whether the user can change the scale of the page at all (zoom in and out). Set to yes to allow scaling and no to disallow scaling. The default is yes. **If you set this to no, then the minimum-scale and maximum-scale are ignored, because scaling is not possible.**

In that case, remove user-scalable=no and see what happens. That might be the fix you need.